# Jwplayer with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jwplayer

I am trying in several ways to start jwplayer in my web app in which i use angularjs.. I need to pass at `file` option a dynamic link of the file. In my controller i can have the dynamic link with a simple function

```
getVideoStreaming: function(file) {
    $scope.fileName = file.name;
    $scope.documentId = document.id;
    $scope.videoSrc = "http://mywebserver.com/" + $scope.fileName;
},
```

this function is called when i click in a button that opens a modal in which i want show the video.

```
<button data-uk-modal="{target:'#videoPlayer'}" data-ng-click="files.getVideoStreaming(file)"> Open video </button>
```

Now the question.. how can i pass this variable to my modal? According to the jwplayer basic configuration this is what i should do:

```
<!-- dialog video -->
<div id="videoPlayer" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog" style="width: 680px!important;">
        <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
        <h3 class="uk-panel-title">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-collection-text"></i>
            {{docName}}
        </h3>
        <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
            playerInstance.setup({
                file: "http://example.com/uploads/file.mp4",
                image: "http://example.com/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
                width: 640,
                height: 360,
                title: 'Basic Video Embed',
                description: 'A video with a basic title and description!'
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

but of course, as i've just said, i need `file` dynamic. Is it possible find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried to use JWPlayer from within a modal, but the directive I wrote should work for you. If not, then maybe you can reverse engineer and adapt. See how I use ng-src for the video file, with the directive is watching for a change.

[ng-jwplayer](https://github.com/ampervue/ngJWPlayer)

or `bower install ng-jwplayer --save`

Then use like:

```
<jwplayer ng-src="{{ videoSrc }}"
         player-options="options"
         player-id="myPlayer1">
</jwplayer>
```

and move your options to

```
...
$scope.videoSrc = "http://mywebserver.com/" + $scope.fileName;
$scope.options = {
  image: "http://example.com/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
  width: 640,
  height: 360,
  title: 'Basic Video Embed',
  description: 'A video with a basic title and description!'
}
```

The package also uses a service to ensure the global jwplayer does not get instantiated multiple times.